# SHA1 libraries - different hash on same binary file

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, hash, cryptography

All is ok, when I call the tool with the text file. But results always are different, when I pass the binary one.
I have to use some js library, like jssha, because my code should be run under several platforms and etc. Binary files processing is the mandatory requirement.

Where is the mistake ?

Node

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
var fs = require('fs');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);


console.time('readFile');
var data = fs.readFileSync(args[0],'utf8').toString();
console.timeEnd('readFile');

console.time('sha1');
shasum.update(data);
var hash = shasum.digest('base64');
console.timeEnd('sha1');

console.log(hash);
```

jssha

```
var jsSHA = require('jssha')
var fs = require('fs');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

console.time('readFile');
var data = fs.readFileSync(args[0],'utf8').toString();
console.timeEnd('readFile');

console.time('sha1');
var shaObj = new jsSHA(data, "TEXT");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("SHA-1", "B64");
console.timeEnd('sha1');

console.log(hash);
```

**Update**

The solution for Node and jsSha is my answer below.  Looks like all JS-implementations of SHA-1 work a bit different with binary data.

Comment: In the future, please make sure to provide enough information to reproduce the problem 100%. In this case, instead of using `readFileSync`, it would have been good to provide a `Buffer` instance with the set of bytes that do not work. That way I could have ensured that my answer properly solved your problem.

Comment: Agree. I was using several files to check the hashing and forgot that I Should have used some buffer

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for Node and jsSHA.

Node

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
  , shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1');
var fs = require('fs');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);


console.time('readFile');
var data = fs.readFileSync(args[0]);
console.timeEnd('readFile');

console.time('sha1');
shasum.update(data);
var hash = shasum.digest('base64');
console.timeEnd('sha1');

console.log(hash);
```

jsSHA

```
var jsSHA = require('jssha')
var fs = require('fs');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

console.time('readFile');
var data = fs.readFileSync(args[0]).toString('hex');
console.timeEnd('readFile');

console.time('sha1');
var shaObj = new jsSHA(data, "HEX");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("SHA-1", "B64");
console.timeEnd('sha1');

console.log(hash);
```